# uniform lighting when taking top view of object

Tags: lighting, image-quality, shadows

What is the best way to take pictures of an object from top view

How should the light be placed ?

*to avoid shadows

and how should we construct the chamber for this ?

*for uniform lighting over the surface of the object(flat object)

[Here](http://www.studiolighting.net/homemade-light-box-for-product-photography/) is a link which was helpful but not in case for top view
Thanks

Comment: Really? A DIY box does not work? How about puting the box with the opening on the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is the same no matter which side of the object you're trying to photograph: **to eliminate shadows, use soft light from all directions.**

**You achieve that with large, diffuse light sources.** In your example, these sources were the white walls of the light box, which bounce light all around the inside of the box. Another way is to build a box with open sides and cover it with translucent white material (fabric, paper, etc.) that you can light from outside the box.

None of that changes when you're shooting a top view. In fact, if you read to the end of the article you linked, there's a sample top view of a necklace that was taken by shooting through a hole in the top of the box. For taller objects, construct a somewhat deeper box, place it on its back so that the open side is facing up, and shoot downward.

**Another option is to use a ring light or a ring flash adapter.** These both attach to your camera lens and emit light from all sides of the lens, minimizing shadows. True ring flashes can be expensive (e.g. [Canon's offering](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ICSNCG6) costs around $500) but offer the most power. Third party LED-based versions are much less expensive but provide much less light, and may or may not be suitable for your use. Ring adapters are essentially ring-shaped reflectors that distribute light from a regular speedlight; they're an inexpensive option, but more awkward to use than the real thing.